# Why won't my Discord.js image files load well?

Tags: file-upload, discord.js, writefile

When I download a .png image file from a Discord attachment to my bot, hosted by Replit, the image won't appear in my files. I have Node v12.16.1 and have no issue importing images directly to my Replit files. When I try to download it on Replit, my Mac says the file can't be opened, so I know it didn't save right. How do I make it download properly?

```
client.on("message" , msg => {

  if (msg.content === "$Time") {
    msg.attachments.forEach(a => {
    {fs.writeFileSync(`./${a.name}`, a.png); 
   }}) 
    
   var interval = setTimeout (function () { msg.channel.send("Sure thing", {files: [`./images/SPOILER_HW.png`]})
       // use the message's channel (TextChannel) to send a new message
       //.catch(console.error);
   },  5000);
  }    
})
```

[How the image appears on Replit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZre6.png)

Answer (score 0):

About that, yes, replit is an IDE that deals with code. You can't open images in it. However you can click on `download the image` to view it if thats all you want to do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I try to ```download the image``` it says that the file can't be opened on my Mac, because the file is damaged or can't be opened.

Comment: You downloaded the file right? That should be enough